# Error while running in applet context

Tags: java, applet

This program is intended to produce a beep sound using applet context.
I got `error cannot find the symbol METHOD SetAudioClip(URL,string)`. Please explain what is url and string in these case.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Boops extends Applet implements MouseListener
{

AudioClip c;

public void init()
{
    c=SetActionClip(getCodeBase(),"beep.ac");
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    c.play();
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove white space in `Set ActionClip`:

```
c=SetActionClip(getCodeBase(),"beep.ac");
```

Comment: `SetActionClip` If that were a method inherited from `java.applet.Applet` or defined in this code (it's not either of those things), it should be `setActionClip` (note case).

Answer (score 1):

```
error ; missing at c=Set ActionClip(getCodeBase(),"beep.ac");
```

Use [`Applet.getAudioClip(URL,String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getAudioClip-java.net.URL-java.lang.String-) instead, which:

> Returns the `AudioClip` object specified by the URL and name arguments.